# How to observe changes for sliding page in Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

What I mean, I want to create something like a sliding window/paginator with a fixed number of items for Room database. For example (look at the image below by link), I create any RecyclerView that should only show 4 elements of some data. If a new item was inserted in the database (fifth item), the window will automatically slide down (will remove the oldest item from list and insert the new item), and RecyclerView adapter will receive changes about deletion and insertion by callback. But the database will have 5 items. I know that there is `PagedList` for pagination, but I don't know how to use it correctly for this behavior.

It is possible to do this in the **Realm** database, making `RealResults` with some filter and observe changes using the listeners `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener`. I want to create such an analogue for Room database.

Is it possible to observe changes like that for Room database? Or is there some ready solution or library?

[Picture to clarify the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCDMC.png)

Comment: Are you familiar with LiveData and ViewModel components?

Comment: @ItamarKerbel Yes, I've tried using LiveData with PageList (without ViewModel because I use MVP), but the observed list is growing and I don't know how to remove "old" items from PageList.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but using a RecyclerView all you need to do is force it to scroll to the end the item on the top will disappear.  recyclerView.scrollToPosition(items.size() - 1);